# how to deploy angular 2 project to heroku?

Tags: deployment, angular, web-deployment

I tried to deploy TUTORIAL: TOUR OF HEROES to a Heroku, but the only answers I found is to use something like angular2 seed, angular2 webpack or angular2 cli.
I tried all of them and still can't figure out how to deploy it.
Can someone give me a detailed instruction of deploying angular 2 app? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a 1-click deploy on the [Angular Universal starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) project.

I then tried to clone it and re-deploy and got stuck because you need to set config vars NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false

I'm still struggling with how to get it to deploy a production build vs. the development build, but it's an example thats up and running

Comment: Further note that the angular universal starter hasn't updated to meet many of the best practices in the style guide. So there's a fair amount of work to clear up tslint.  In addition, a hint was that you need to adjust the server.ts file to map to your asset folder (or I changed to images) to show your static image files (and this needs to be in src vs public)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the CLI to generate the product, you can do

```
ng build --prod (and also add the aot flag if you like) --aot
```

Since it's a static site, if you don't need an underlying server, you can upload the files to S3 (or cloud provider of choice or their cdn) and 200 redirect all queries to /index.html